# Can Bran see the future at will that people don't know about?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

It's established in *Game of Thrones* that Bran can do the following things:

**Warging, Greensighting (seeing past and present), being a three-eyed raven.**

I'm not really sure  if Bran can see into the future because as it seems, Bran can see only visions (which is not in his control) and not the things about to happen.

**There are big things he knows will happen which are visions.**

1. The fate of Kings Landing (the dragon flying over KL and the destroyed throne room in KL castle)
2. Winterfell consumed by water - Theon seizing Winterfell

**These are big things he knows will happen which are visions.**

1. That he would be king (In S8E6, he says "Why do you think I'm here, when Tyrion asks if he would be the king of 7 kingdoms)
2. Gave knife to Arya knowing well she would kill the Night King one day

But in a lot of scenes he always seems to be a know-it-all-in-advance guy who knows **insignificant things that are not vision level worthy** (as the ones mentioned above).

1. Knows Jamies about to come to Winterfell
2. Knows Theon is about to die
   etc.

**Can he actually see the future at will? Even insignificant things? And is he not letting people know that he can see the future?**

[Question comes from the fact that Bran can see Past, Current but not Future (except as visions) - but he seems to be knowing really small things about to happen apart from the major things about to happen]

Comment: Where are these visions you speak of, with him seeing himself as king and all?

Comment: @zibadawatimmy when Tyrion asks if Bran would rule the 7 kingdoms, Bran says "Why do you think I am here" implying very strongly he knew beforehand that he would be the king of the seven kingdoms. Hes had a vision which we weren't showed OR he just knows the future but isn't keen on letting people know

Comment: While I agree that was a strange and seemingly prescient line, that's no evidence of an actual vision.  You're just assuming.  Maybe he sat around thinking to himself about what might happen, it occurred to him that someone might try to install him as King, and decided "yeah, I could work with that." Did any of these things you say he had visions of actually have *actual* visions stated or shown to us in the books or show?

Comment: we weren't shown the visions, but the only two ways in which Bran may have known about these happenings are if (1) he has visions (2) he can see the future at will. The visions i spoke about -  3 and 4 are visions that happened in the show and books. 1 and 2 are presumed to be visions or conveniently he CAN see the future.

Comment: If you can provide references for (3) and (4) I would like that very much.  But then you sort of know the answer already, yes?

Comment: @zibadawatimmy ive separated the sure things from the unsure things

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93856/discussion-between-anu7-and-zibadawa-timmy).

Comment: Related question on the Sci-fi and Fantasy site: [Why did Bran come all this way?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/212832/why-did-bran-come-all-this-way)

Answer (score 7):

**Almost certainly no.**

While it's logical to conclude that his time spent witnessing and contemplating the past and present give him great insight into the motivation of others and accurately anticipate their actions and intentions, it is very unlikely he has the ability to "see" the future at his own discretion.

Case in point, S7E7.

> Bran: "Jon isn't really my father's son. He's the son of Rhaegar Targaryen and my aunt, Lyanna Stark. He was born in a tower in Dorne. His last name isn't really Snow, it's Sand."
>
> Sam: "It's not."
>
> ...
>
> Bran: "Are you certain?"
>
> [Read more](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=game-of-thrones&episode=s07e07)

We can gather from this exchange (and Bran's mistake in Jon's legitimate birth) two options:

1. Bran didn't know anything about the future conundrum of Jon's claim to the throne, which would be a *huge* issue to miss for someone who can conjure visions at will,

OR

2. Bran knew but for reasons unknown pretended like he didn't.

The most logical conclusion is that **Bran can't readily "see" future events.**